# SwiftUI - using all but one values of Enum for different Pickers

Tags: swift, enums, swiftui, picker

In my app, I need to use a `Picker` in two different places. In one place, it's to set a property to one of three values: A, B, or C. But, in another place, I want to use the picker to filter a array of items to show either all items (no filter) or only the A, B, or C items.

So, my first attempt was to create an `enum` like so:

```
enum Category {
  case all
  case A
  case B
  case C
}
```

Using this, I can filter my list successfully. But, when I try to create a new item in the array, I don't want `all` to be an option. The user should only see a picker with A, B, and C.

I could try:

```
enum Category {
  case A
  case B
  case C
}
```

but then how do I *add* the `all` option for the filter picker?

(To address some comments below, here are some more details on the specific thing I'm try to accomplish...

A tournament can be a men's, women's, or mixed tournament. On the screen where I list the tournaments, I want to be able to show *all* tournaments or just the men's, just the women's or just the mixed tournaments. So, I have a picker that spans the width of the iPhone. Looks and works great.

Obviously, when adding a new item to the list, I have to specify its category, but not "all". Also a picker.

So, in one case, I need three values, in the other case, I need the same three values with "All" added at the beginning.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define your `enum` without the `all` case, because `all` is not a valid `Category` for an item. (This is a programming guideline known as “[make illegal states unrepresentable](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=make+illegal+state+unrepresentable)”.)

```
enum Category: Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case a
    case b
    case c
}
```

With that definition, the `Picker` for setting an item's property can look like this:

```
Picker("Category", selection: $category) {
    ForEach(Category.allCases, id: \.self) { category in
        Text(verbatim: "\(category)")
            .tag(category)
    }
}
```

Then you should recognize that your filter is *optional*. You can filter by item category, or you can perform no filtering. So your filter property should be declared optional:

```
@Binding var categoryFilter: Category?
```

The `Picker` for setting the filter then needs to be careful to use optional tags:

```
Picker("Category Filter", selection: $categoryFilter) {
    Text("None")
        .tag(Category?.none)
    ForEach(Category.allCases, id: \.self) { category in
        Text(verbatim: "\(category)")
            .tag(Category?.some(category))
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, this looks nice, too. So, I can add `Text` items to a `Picker`? And, when I select the "None" option, categoryFilter will be set to nil?

Comment: Yes, you use `Text` to add items to a `Picker`. Yes, if you choose `None`, it will set `categoryFilter` to `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create enum in this way

```
enum Category {
    case all
    case A
    case B
    case C
    
    static let categories: [Category] = [.A, .B, .C]
}
```

And then use the categories array when you need to choose among three.

Comment: This was perfect! Quick, easy, effective. Thank you.

Comment: Two years later, I realize that this is not the way to go, as "all" should not actually be an option, though I do like the clever solution which might be useful in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your enum `CaseIterable` and then you can use the `allCases` property when you want to display all enum values, and use a `filter` when you only want certain cases displayed.

**NOTE:** In my sample code, you'll need to replace `selection: .constant(Category.a)` with an `@Binding`

```
struct Test {
    enum Category: String, CaseIterable {
        case all = "All"
        case a = "A"
        case b = "B"
        case c = "C"
    }
    
    struct TestView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Picker("Picker Title", selection: .constant(Category.a)) {
                    ForEach(Category.allCases, id: \.self) { category in
                        Text(category.rawValue).tag(category)
                    }
                }
                
                Picker("Picker Title", selection: .constant(Category.a)) {
                    ForEach(Category.allCases.filter({ $0 != .all }), id: \.self) { category in
                        Text(category.rawValue).tag(category)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to keep "all" out of the enum, and then ForEach over ["All"] + Category.allCases, rather than the filter?

Comment: From reading the original post `but then how do I add the all option for the filter picker?`, there is a case where "All" needs to be presented.  Personally, from a UI perspective, this may not be the best way to allow the user to select these "categories".  Perhaps a list of available categories (A, B, C) and a button "Select All" that auto selects.

Comment: @Jack I added some more detail about my reasons for what I'm doing. Does my question make more sense with that extra info?

Comment: @Shadowrun Good question. Maybe it comes down to how many times the 4-option version is used vs. the 3-option version?

Comment: @rob-mayoff is right - all is not a category - You _could_ view the 4-way enum as directly representing the rows in the UI, then All would be one of those. But don't call such an enum "Category", because All is not a category, and you're likely going to need the 3-way Category enum in your model layer anyway, so instead of having 2 similar enums, represent your arranged row's model with Category.allCases + The "all" row

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question if I understood you correctly.

1. Modify your enum to implement the CaseIterable  take a look at it below.

   ```
    enum Category:CaseIterable{
     case all
     case A
     case B   
     case C
    }
   ```
2. Filter out where your category matches the all case. Example below.

   ```
   let preferredcategory = Category.allCases.filter{ return $0 !=  Category.all}
   ```
3. To test our result see the code below.

   ```
    print(preferredcategory.count)
    for catname in preferredcategory {
    print("Hello, \(catname)!")
   }
   ```
4. You can read more on this respective pages.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable/2994869-allcases

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-list-all-cases-in-an-enum-using-caseiterable

Thanks.

So you can use the preferredCategory variable to show the user your category for the one you do not want all to show. you can also use the same filter to show only the part of the enum that has all case as well.

Also, the good thing is you get to keep your enum and reuse it everywhere in your application without having to hardcode values. if you want to show only All you just have to filter out the remaining case.

Some people may want to downvote without a valid reasons but if you believe the approach is wrong feel free to edit or leave a comment on how to improve the solution.

Comment: I am sure this is the way to solve it without having to hardcode values everywhere within your application and I will not feel bad even someone downvoted without a valid reasons as to why the downvote.

Comment: This is, I guess, the most easiest way to do it. I use this way almost all the time. If the person who did do the 'minus one' explain the why maybe I would be understanding why this isn't good to use it.